# Recursive Linked List Difference

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I just got this question from text book, but I just can't seem to figure it out what the answer is. The question asks "Explain in one sentence what the function does, and what is 'bad' about this function?" (It does not have to do with programming style).

And by the way, what's the difference 
between "return f(x, p->next)" and "p->next = f(x, p->next)" ? I just can't seem to figure out the difference between these two.

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* f(int x, Node* p) {
    if (p == nullptr) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else if (p->data == x) {
        return f(x, p->next);
    }
    else {
        p->next = f(x, p->next);
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what would happen for a very long linked list. What would happen in that case? (Hint: what's the name of this website?)

Comment: stackoverflow. Because it can't hold any more space of memory?

Comment: The stack is limited. Usually a few MB.

Comment: @MrEricSir what's the difference between return f(x, p->next); and p->next = f(x, p->next);?

Comment: FYI, any recursive algorithm can be converted into an iterative algorithm.

Comment: @e0k yeah I know, but I just want to learn recursive functions in depth, and I still can't figure what's the difference between return f(x, p->next); and p->next = f(x, p->next);?

Comment: One returns a value, the other makes an assignment...

Comment: @e0k let's say the my linked list is head->1->2->3->4->null. If I called f(3, head), what would it return? and what if I called f(5, head), what would it return? I am really confused, sorry.

Comment: Which version is correct? `else if (p->data = x) [` or `else if (p->data == x) [`? Original post had `=` but @domenkavran changed it to `==`.

Comment: @JackDeeth yeah domenkavran one was the correct one.

Comment: @JackDeeth do you mind to tell me what's the difference between the two recursive functions?

Comment: @FelixChang well, `=` is an error; calling `f` will run to the end of the list putting all elements to `x`. And with `==` - I had to run through it with the debugger, but it will remove the element with that value from the list.

Answer (score 2):

What `f` does is walk through the linked list, removing any elements which hold the value `x`.

```
else if (p->data == x) { // if the next element has our target value
    return f(x, p->next); // make that element's next element, become our own next element
}
```

What's bad about it is that `std::vector` exists, and while

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), x), vec.end());
```

isn't the most elegant line of code, it's a heck of a lot more comprehendable and recognisable than recursive pointer functions.

Also `f` leaks memory. The removed element doesn't get deleted; `f` just overwrites the pointer which knows where it is.